# Internationalization file in SpringBoot Application

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I have Springboot Application for Rest Service. And rest services are documented using Swagger/ springfox annotations, and I want use i18n file properties for internationalization feautures in my App....

as I do in the controller I dynamically retrieve the property of the 'message' in annotation @ApiResponses?

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK, message = "Successful login to platform"),
        @ApiResponse(code = HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED, message = "Unauthorized request to platform")
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems as of now (2018-08-08) it's currently not supported. You can take a look at the issue here: [link](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/274)

Comment: So, and there is a way to inject them through a properties file

@Autowired
private Environment env;
...
String myMessage = env.getProperty ("my.custom.message"))

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue.

First if you look at current Springfox (Version 2.9.2) documentation, they supports following annotations out of the box:

```
@ApiParam#value()
@ApiImplicitParam#value()
@ApiModelProperty#value()
@ApiOperation#value()
@ApiOperation#notes()
@RequestParam#defaultValue()
@RequestHeader#defaultValue()
```

It took me some time to get dynamic `@ApiResponse` message, so I will post a reply to help others.

Solution is based on https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1180

First I added following to my swagger configuration file:

```
@Bean
public TranslationOperationBuilderPlugin translationPlugin() {
    return new TranslationOperationBuilderPlugin();
}

//important to keep this LOWEST_PRECEDENCE!!!
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public static class TranslationOperationBuilderPlugin implements OperationBuilderPlugin {

    @Autowired
    protected Environment env;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(DocumentationType delimiter) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(OperationContext context) {
        Set<ResponseMessage> messages = context.operationBuilder().build().getResponseMessages();

        Set<ResponseMessage> translated = new HashSet<>();
        for (ResponseMessage untranslated : messages) {
            String translation = env.getProperty(untranslated.getMessage());

            translated.add(new ResponseMessage(untranslated.getCode(),
                    translation,
                    untranslated.getResponseModel(),
                    untranslated.getHeaders(),
                untranslated.getVendorExtensions()
            ));
        }
        context.operationBuilder().responseMessages(translated);
    }
}
```

On controller class I add `@PropertySource(value= "classpath:swagger.properties", encoding="UTF-8")`
This file is located inside usual resources directory and contains `code_400=my message`

And on method in controller

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = ResponseKeys.MESSAGE_400)
})
```

And finally ResponseKeys contains:

```
public class ResponseKeys {

    /* 4xx messages */
    public static final String MESSAGE_400 = "code_400";

}
```